# Frequent Rejection of Emails: 554 - MTA's Poor Reputation

Tags: email, email-server, email-bounces

My colleagues and I share an email address and for the last 3 to 4 weeks, we have been receiving frequent error messages when sending out emails to our clients.

It is generally the `554 - MTA's poor reputation` which keeps bouncing back to us. I checked if our server was blacklisted but apparently it wasn't. Other employees from the same servers aren't having the same problem.

Can anybody please help to resolve this problem? Please let me know if you need further information. Thank you in advance.

```
The original message was received at Thu, 3 May 2012 16:40:18 +0900
from host-41-141.citramedia.net.id [203.191.41.141] (may be forged)

----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----

(reason: 554-m1pismtp01-037.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net)

----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to smtp.secureserver.net.:
<<< 554-m1pismtp01-009.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net
<<< 554 Your access to this mail system has been rejected due to the sending MTA's poor reputation. If you believe that this failure is in error, please contact the intended recipient via alternate means.
... while talking to mailstore1.secureserver.net.:
<<< 554-m1pismtp01-037.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net
<<< 554 Your access to this mail system has been rejected due to the sending MTA's poor reputation. If you believe that this failure is in error, please contact the intended recipient via alternate means.
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
```

Comment: That does look like a blacklist of some sort..

Answer (score 2):

There is not a lot you can do in order to immediately solve this problem. Every mail administrator decides autonomously which emails he wants to accept and which to reject.

Your best bet is to try to contact the mail administrator of this mail server (through web form, other email account or by phone). Otherwise, you could always send your emails for the recipients which cause problems through an alternate mail server with a better reputation (e.g. by forwarding these mails directly on your MTA to another MTA).

Some ideas in order to improve the situation in the long term:

- Make sure no spam is sent through your IP address and respond to abuse requests promptly.
- Monitor blacklists to be informed when your IP address gets listed.
- List your IP address in whitelists (e.g. dnswl.org).